# How install kernel header in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit whenever, i am giving following command in the teminal

```
dpkg -s kernel
```

or

```
dpkg -s kernel-headers
```

both the output shows kernel or kernel headers are not installed .. How to solve this issue?

I have already tried to install the same

using ,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

but the problem is not solved.

I am new to Ubuntu .. Please help me

Comment: What is _the real problem_? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` before running the Kernel header command

Comment: i want to install Exata virutal interface on it .. For which it is prerequisite to install kernel and kernel header. In the manual it says try the following command: dpkg -s kernel or dpkg -s kernel-headers. if the output is none then install them first

Comment: This installs lots of zero byte files that can not be used yet. e.g. 
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-55-generic/include/config/modversions.h  seems some kind of make command is needed as well

Answer (score 4):

kernel headers are provided by `linux-headers-$(uname -r)-generic` packages. Run:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
```

to see the installed headers.